# Graph $f(x,y)=\ln(x)-y$

Tags: graphing-functions

I'm trying to graph $f(x,y)=\ln(x)-y$, however, I am not sure how as all of my tools are refusing to graph it.

Can you please help me?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by the graph of $\ln(x) - y$?  Do you mean $z = \ln(x) - y$, $0 = \ln(x) - y$, some other constant $c = \ln(x) - y$?  It doesn't make sense to just graph $\ln(x) - y$ because you need an equation $(=)$ to be able to graph something.

Comment: @DMcMor Sorry, I meant $f(x,y)=ln(x)-y$

Comment: So since it is a function from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}$, you want a $3$D representation of the graph ?

Comment: It really depends on the tools you have available. In Mathematica, for example, you would use `Plot3D`.

Comment: @TheSilverDoe Only in 2D with $x$ and $y$ axes.

Comment: @Peter You cannot draw it in 2D! You have two input values $x$ and $y$ and so you need one more axis to represent the value of $f$.

Answer (score 2):

Note that there is no way to plot this in 2D because you would need an equation of the form $f(x,y) = 0$, and what you have is $f(x,y) = \ln(x) - y$, which can be thought of as $f(x,y) = z$.  That means you need a 3D plot to visualize it.

There are several good online options for plotting 3D graphs.  Here are two good ones:

1.) [Calcplot3D](https://c3d.libretexts.org/CalcPlot3D/index.html?type=z;z=ln(x)-y;visible=true;umin=-6;umax=6;vmin=-6;vmax=6;grid=50;format=normal;alpha=-1;constcol=rgb(255,0,0);view=0;contourcolor=red;fixdomain=true&type=window;hsrmode=3;nomidpts=true;anaglyph=-1;center=-6.513098527506768,-7.382907616178462,1.7527757135334454,1;focus=0,0,0,1;up=-0.028634991195109524,0.2547385033929391,0.9665859155648717,1;transparent=false;alpha=140;twoviews=false;unlinkviews=false;axisextension=0.7;xaxislabel=x;yaxislabel=y;zaxislabel=z;edgeson=true;faceson=true;showbox=true;showaxes=true;showticks=true;perspective=true;centerxpercent=0.5;centerypercent=0.5;rotationsteps=30;autospin=true;xygrid=false;yzgrid=false;xzgrid=false;gridsonbox=false;gridplanes=false;gridcolor=rgb(128,128,128);xmin=-6;xmax=6;ymin=-6;ymax=6;zmin=-6;zmax=6;xscale=5;yscale=5;zscale=5;zcmin=-4;zcmax=4;zoom=0.277778;xscalefactor=1;yscalefactor=1;zscalefactor=1), which produces the following plot.  This one is my personal favorite, but you might want to see [here](https://c3d.libretexts.org/CalcPlot3D/CalcPlot3D-Help/section-2.html) for key commands for camera controls.[image]

2.) [Geogebra](https://www.geogebra.org/3d/gu3rkwpa), which produces the plot [image]

Answer (score 1):

You cannot draw it on the $Oxy$-plane. You have two input values $x$ and $y$ and so you need one more axis to represent the value of $f$. Below is the graph drawn via GeoGebra:

[image]